# C# Buddy Classes / Meta Data and Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

I am trying to use reflection to check if properties on a given class have a ReadOnly attribute set.  The classes I am using are MVC View Models (using a partial "buddy" class for the metadata.

```
 public partial class AccountViewModel  
{
    public virtual Int32 ID { get; set; } 
    public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }    

} 
[MetadataType(typeof(AccountViewModelMetaData))]
public partial class AccountViewModel  
{
    class AccountViewModelMetaData
    {
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public virtual Int32 ID { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Balance")]
        [DataType(DataType.Currency)] 
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I want to check if "Balance" has the ReadOnly property.  If i set the ReadOnly attribute on the Balance property of AccountViewModel, i can retrieve it this way:

```
Type t = typeof(AccountViewModel);
PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("Balance");  
bool isReadOnly =  ReadOnlyAttribute.IsDefined(pi,typeof( ReadOnlyAttribute);
```

I can't retrieve the attribute info if it is on the meta data class.  How can i check if the attribute exists?  I have meta data classes defined for all my view models, and need a generic way to check for attributes on meta data classes.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

the solution is to use `GetCustomAttributes` to get MetaData types and check the properties on those as well...

```
Type t = typeof(MyClass);
PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(PropertyName);  
bool isReadOnly = ReadOnlyAttribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute));

if (!isReadOnly)
{
    //check for meta data class.
    MetadataTypeAttribute[] metaAttr = (MetadataTypeAttribute[])t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MetadataTypeAttribute),true);

    if (metaAttr.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (MetadataTypeAttribute attr in metaAttr)
        {
            t = attr.MetadataClassType;
            pi = t.GetProperty(PropertyName);

            if (pi != null) isReadOnly = ReadOnlyAttribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute));

            if (isReadOnly) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that you're checking that the attribute exists and not that it is defined has `true`. Have you considered what happens if the property is defined has `[ReadOnlyAttribute(false)]`?

Comment: Sorry but could not understand your solution. :(

Answer (score 1):

A short but working example follows, note that I made the nested class `internal` in order to be visible to the outside.

```
public partial class AccountViewModel
{
    internal class AccountViewModelMetaData
    {
        public virtual Int32 ID { get; set; }
        [ReadOnlyAttribute(false)]
        public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }
    }

    public virtual Int32 ID { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type metaClass = typeof(AccountViewModel.AccountViewModelMetaData);

        bool hasReadOnlyAtt = HasReadOnlyAttribute(metaClass, "Balance");

        Console.WriteLine(hasReadOnlyAtt);
    }

    private static bool HasReadOnlyAttribute(Type type, string property)
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty(property);

        return ReadOnlyAttribute.IsDefined(pi, typeof(ReadOnlyAttribute));
    }
}
```

Also be aware that this checks for the existence of the attribute. You can has in this example specify the attribute but provide the value of `false`. If you want to check if the property is read-only or not, you can't only use the method `ReadOnlyAttribute.IsDefined`.