# Using reflection to get property attributes from a metadata class

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, .net-4.0, attributes

I have a LINQ generated class called Project.

I wanted to add some attributes to the generated properties, so I defined a partial class with the MetadataType attribute.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(Project_HiddenProps))]
public partial class Project : IProject
{
    // There are also a few additional properties defined here.
}

public class Project_HiddenProps
{
    [HiddenColumn]
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; } 
    // Id is an auto-generated property that I've added a custom attribute to
}
```

Later, I use reflection to try to get the attributes of this property.

```
var customAttributes = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

I only get one attribute, though, of type `System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute`.  My `HiddenColumn` attribute is not included in the collection.  My question is how to get at these metadata properties using reflection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using something like LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities?

Comment: I've found an answer for your problem (and mine) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910532/attribute-isdefined-doesnt-see-attributes-applied-with-metadatatype-class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reflect the other class, using a convention approach:

```
var type = Type.GetType(entityType.FullName + "_HiddenProps," + entityType.AssemblyQualifiedName);
type.GetProperty("Id").GetCustomAttributes(false);
```

The buddy class cannot be automatically merged with the core component.  That is only used for internal framework metadata (assume this is MVC, or maybe dynamic data?)

As @CyanLite mentioned in the comments, you can use the Meta class from the metadata attribute [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364610/c-sharp-buddy-classes-meta-data-and-reflection/2364766#2364766) (the link Cyan added).

Comment: It's dynamic data, but with web forms.

Comment: OK.  The result will still be the same unfortunately though.

Comment: Trying to use this, but getting an exception of "The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)"

Comment: Then I was probably wrong when I said: entityType.AssemblyQualifiedName, essentially define the name of the assembly here, so it generates a string like: "type,assemblyname", as in: "MyNS.Project_HiddenProps,MyAssembly"

Comment: Got it - instead of entityType.AssemblyQualifiedName it's entityType.Assembly.FullName.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: This answer is WRONG.  You can dynamically fetch the Meta classes with the MetadataAttribute.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2364766/613620

Comment: @CyanLite It's not wrong; it's a perfectly viable convention-based solution, and does a very similar function as the link you provided.  Your link works great too; I added it to the post with your credit.